# XMLHttpRequest not caching basic HTTP auth in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I am trying to authorize a user with basic HTTP auth with an `XMLHttpRequest` object in Firefox 25 in a custom extension.

The flow is like so:

1. hit URL that is HTTP basic auth protected, authorize using either `xml.open('GET', url, true, username, password)` or `xml.setRequestHeaders('Authorization', 'Basic someBASE64encodedSTRING==')`.
2. be redirected to another, arbitrary, non-HTTP-basic-protected URL.
3. be redirected back to my protected URL from step 1.  Between step 1 and 3, the basic auth is lost, and on step (3) the user is again presented with the basic HTTP auth modal.

Is there a way to force the browser (specifically firefox) to cache the authorization?

In Chrome I was able to solve this issue using `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired` listener: https://gist.github.com/Lordnibbler/2b616adfa4662ece5095

Answer (score 0):

As HTTP is stateless protocol...
in Step 1) once you authenticate - web server should return you "session id" - unique string by which web server knows, that you were authenticated. You should save that "session id" to a cookie.
2) maybe step 2 returns session id - also possibility. Otherwise its irrelevant.
3) make sure that you send "session id" with your requests - should work

p.s. I just popped here randomly... I have never developed any firefox extension.